# Почему find находит лишь одно значение в БД?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

Только начинаю вкатываться в MongoDB, и уже как стать начинаются проблемы.

У меня есть коллекция с именами пользователей и их ID. После того как пользователь ищет информацию о себе в Боте, скрипт выполняет следующий шаг - он уточняет через ID Discord серверов имя этих серверов, чтобы было удобно их вывести. Итог - Mongo находит лишь одну строку с сервером, а **первую** оставляет в None. Буду рад если подскажете как исправить этот казус.

Код:

```py
            for i in row['fractions']:
                print(i)
                userfrac = factions.find_one({'id': int(i)})
                print(userfrac)
                embed.add_field(name="---", value="---", inline=True)
```

Входные данные:

```
1142101486352998530

1114633110454272000
```

Вывод:

```
1142101486352998530
None
1114633110454272000
{'_id': ObjectId('64feeb917a131d558f1f9356'), 'name': 'Psi-IX', 'id': 1.114633110454272e+18, 'users': [8.607867706891305e+17, 9.028601652320788e+17]}
```

ID серверов полностью идентичен

Comment: Потому что потеря точности. `1142101486352998530 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` -> true. Внутри монги же JavaScript.